# Google app api with freshdesk api error

Tags: api, google-apps-script, freshdesk

On using the freshdesk api from google app script getting an error

```
"{"code":"invalid_content_type","message":"Content-Type header is set to . It should be set to application/json"}"
```

The code used for this

```
function hd_getTickets(){//using v2
    var API_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    var headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json','Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(API_KEY + ':X')    };
    var data = {  "query":"\"priority:3\"" };
    var ENDPOINT = 'https://xxxxxxx.freshdesk.com/api/v2'; 
    var url = ENDPOINT + '/search/tickets';  
    var options = {      'method': 'get', muteHttpExceptions: true,'headers': headers,'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)};
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}
```

Changing the endpoint and removing the payload from options work so assuming authorization and header is fine

```
var url = ENDPOINT + '/tickets';  
var options = {'method':'get','headers':headers, muteHttpExceptions: true};
```

Using postman this works

```
https://xxxxxxx.freshdesk.com/api/v2/search/tickets?query="priority:3"
```

with header set as

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues found
1) web site does not support payload based get.
2) google apps doesn't support special characters in url.

Adding parameters to the original url and encoding the double quotes works.

```
  var ENDPOINT = 'https://xxxxxx.freshdesk.com/api/v2';   
  var query ='query='+encodeURIComponent("\"priority")+":1"+encodeURIComponent("\"");
  var url = ENDPOINT + '/search/tickets?'+query;  
  var options = {'method': 'get', muteHttpExceptions: true,'headers': headers}; 
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a GET request to the API with the Payload variable in the options. 
In my opinion payloads are used for POST requests.

Construct the URL with the query parameters and send it without the Payload.
Example: 'https://domain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/search/tickets?query="priority:3"'

See details here: [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)
Freshdesk API Doc: https://developers.freshdesk.com/api/#filter_tickets

Comment: this brings me to a second problem that probably should be a different post. I get this error - 

Invalid argument: https://xxxxxx.freshdesk.com/api/v2/search/tickets?query="priority:3"